# Mongoose - Updating a subdocument using findOneAndUpdate

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, express, mongoose, redux

I don't know if the specific method just doesn't work. Should findOneAndUpdate work with subdocuments?

Using react / redux / express.

The route:

```
  app.route("/api/positions/:position_id").put(function(req, res) {
const _id = req.params.position_id;
const update = req.body;
process.nextTick(function() {
  // for each element in req.body -> I will update the correct field
  Project.findOneAndUpdate({_id : _id}, update, { new: true }, function(
    err,
    updatedDoc
  ) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    else if (!updatedDoc)
      res.json({ message: "No Position Found", _id });
    else {
      console.log(updatedDoc);
      res.json({
        message: "Update Successful",
        updatedDoc
      }); }
  });
});
```

});

Postman returns:

```
{
  "message": "No Position Found",
  "_id": "58d1908861f3513dc0c85f7d"
}
```

But the subdocument definitely exists in the DB:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58c32c197f37c62a944f0ad2"
    },
    "name": "One",
    "phrase": "Two",
    "description": "Three",
    "userID": "58ac8e0ec1d5dc37043b8a7f",
    "open_positions": [
        {
            "position_title": "Master Chief",
            "position_description": "Superman chief",
            "position_tags": [
                "Healthcare",
                "Finance",
                "Consumer Products"
            ]
        },
        {
            "position_title": "Master Chief",
            "position_description": "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor ",
            "position_tags": [
                "Healthcare",
                "Finance",
                "Consumer Products",
                "Healthcare",
                "Finance",
                "Consumer Products",
                "Healthcare",
                "Finance",
                "Consumer Products"
            ]
        },
        {
            "position_description": "please join us we are the best",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "58d18fb8b1f3272de8b89158"
            },
            "position_tags": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        {
            "position_description": "please join us we are the best",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "58d18fc9d993233df4e52ace"
            },
            "position_tags": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        {
            "position_description": "please join us we are the best",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "58d18fdcd993233df4e52acf"
            },
            "position_tags": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        {
            "position_title": "BEST POSITION",
            "position_description": "please join us we are the best",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "58d18ffbd993233df4e52ad0"
            },
            "position_tags": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        {
            "position_title": "BEST POSITION",
            "position_description": "please join us we are the best",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "58d1908861f3513dc0c85f7d"
            },
            "position_tags": [
                ""
            ]
        }
    ],
    "fields": [
        "Healthcare",
        "Finance",
        "Consumer Products"
    ],
    "skills": [],
    "dateAdded": {
        "$date": "2017-03-10T22:43:37.544Z"
    },
    "size": "2-5",
    "stage": "development",
    "visible": true,
    "__v": 5
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

This is the schema if it helps:

```
// schema for open positions in a project
var positionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  position_title: String,
  position_description: String,
  position_tags: Array,
  archived: Boolean,
  archivedDate: Date
});

// schema for single project data
var projectSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userID: String,
  name: String,
  phrase: String,
  visible: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  },
  positions: Boolean,
  stage: {
    type: String,
    default: "Idea"
  },
  size: {
    type: String,
    default: "1"
  },
  members: String,
  dateAdded: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  description: String,
  skills: Array,
  fields: {
    type: Array,
    default: ["Other"]
  },
  open_positions: [positionSchema],
  archived: Boolean,
  archivedDate: Date
});

// expose schema to app
module.exports = mongoose.model("Project", projectSchema);
```

Comment: Can you try `Project.findOneAndUpdate({"open_positions._id" : _id}, { "open_positions.$" : update }, { new: true }....` ?

Comment: Holy crap that worked. What just happened? How did it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You query the  `_id` field inside the `open_positions` embedded array. So in the query part you've to reference `open_positions` followed by its id.

When you use array reference in query part you get placeholder `$` positional operator which has reference to the index of the matching array element and in the update part Mongo replaces the `$` with the previously found array index  followed by replacing the array element with your `update` doc.

Use

```
Project.findOneAndUpdate({"open_positions._id" : _id}, { "open_positions.$" : update }, { new: true }....
```